# ssh does not try to provide private keys for github over ssh

Tags: ssh, git, github, ssh-keys

I uploaded my public key to github and have my private key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

Even after adding RSAAuthentication=yes and PubkeyAuthentication=yes in ~/.ssh/config, ssh does not seem to try any of the private keys:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
....
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

I believe it is supposed to be something more like:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key id_rsa...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

I believe I have the permissions on ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/id_rsa set correctly:

```
/home/doriad/.ssh $ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 40
drwx------  2 doriad users  4096 Oct 16 16:05 .
drwx------ 81 doriad users 12288 Oct 16 13:22 ..
-rw-------  1 doriad users   174 Oct 16 16:05 config
-rw-------  1 doriad users   147 Oct 16 16:05 config~
-rw-------  1 doriad users  1679 Sep 23 11:45 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 doriad users   402 Sep 23 11:45 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r-----  1 doriad users  5979 Sep 23 11:37 known_hosts
```

Can anyone explain why it is not trying my private key?

Comment: Can you share more of your .ssh/config with us? This should work out of the box, even without an .ssh/config, so I suspect it is something in there.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner My entire ~/.ssh/config is: RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

Comment: Those both default to yes, so they shouldn't matter. What about `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`? Anything not commented out in there?

Comment: Please add the output from `ls -al ~/.ssh` to your question.  Permissions are often the culprit, SSH is pretty strict about key permissions.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner There was a line in my /etc/ssh/ssh_config like: PreferredAuthentications gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive . I added PreferredAuthentications publickey to my ~/.ssh/config and then it worked correctly! I don't understand why it said "Trying private key id_rsa..." in my output if it was not trying to use the publickey authentication?

Comment: It does seem strange that it would say that, my guess is that it was iterating over the methods that github.com supports and trying each of those, and only once it had decided to try pubickey authentication did it see if your PreferredAuthentications allowed that.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I suppose that makes sense. If you want to add an answer about checking PreferredAuthentications and the possible explanation, I'll accept it.